# Getting 404 for HttpPost Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table of records being displayed in a partial view and some of them have no ID values. So I am trying to use an alternative field as an ID when clicking the Edit link for a particular record. I'm not sure if I can legally have two Post action methods, even though I am using different methods names and params.

Currently, if I click on a record with an ID the correct action method gets called. If I select a record with no ID (instead using an "account" string ID which is unique), I get a 404.

**RouteConfig:**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

**Partial View:**

```
...
<td>
    @if (item.ID != null)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBudget", new { id = item.ID })
    }
    else if (item.Account != null)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAccountBudget", new { account = item.Account })
    }
</td>
```

**BudgetsController:**

```
// POST: Budgets/Edit/5
[Route("edit/{id?}")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditBudget(int? id = null, FormCollection collection = null)
{
    ...
    // Responding correctly for URL: http://localhost:4007/edit/19
}

[Route("editaccountbudget/{account}")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditAccountBudget(string account)
{
    ...
    // Getting 404 for URL: http://localhost:4007/editaccountbudget/6000..130
}
```

Comment: `[Route("budgets/` is not compatible with `@Html.ActionLink("Edit"`,  I guess.

Comment: Updated. Still getting 404.

Comment: Try this `[Route("edit/editaccountbudget/{account}")]`

Comment: Still 404:http://localhost:4007/edit/editaccountbudget/6000..145

Comment: @IrishChieftain: It's not seems you use post here. Try to remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some have pointed out, this is a GET request. If the ID was null, I had to pass the model because I needed more than the account ID to construct the database query.

**Partial View:**

```
@if (item.ID != null)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBudget", new { id = item.ID })
}
else if (item.Account != null)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBudget", new { account = item.Account,
        SelectedDepartment = item.SelectedDepartment, SelectedYear = item.SelectedYear })
}
```

**BudgetsController:**

```
// GET
public ActionResult EditBudget(int? id, BudgetsViewModel model)
{
    repo = new BudgetDemoRepository();
    if (id != null)
    {
        // Pass id to repository class
    }
    else
    {
        // Pass account and other params to repository class

    }

    return View(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that EditBudget is your controller name , you can change
your route to this to avoid confusing ( or leave as it is since the attribute route will be ignored) and remove [POST] from your action too:

```
[Route("~EditBudget/EditAccountBudget/{account}")]
```

Also change:

```
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAccountBudget", new new { account = item.Account })
```

To:

```
        @Html.ActionLink("EditAccountBudget", "EditBudget", new { account = item.Account })
```

If you use razor pages template controls you need to have both controller and action parts of  the route according your route mapping. If you use ajax or httpclient you can have any syntax of route.

Comment: Curious as to why the route attribute is ignored? The first parameter to ActionLink is the text of that link, so that doesn't really change anything.

Comment: @Html.ActionLink generates  <a> tag with controller and action name not routing.

Comment: You're correct in this case it seems. But there are option to pass routes in the API from what I can see. I found a solution and will post answer.

Answer (score 1):

`ActionLink` renders a regular anchor (<a />) tag, so it only does <kbd>GET</kbd> not <kbd>POST</kbd>. If you want to <kbd>POST</kbd> values, you need to use an actual form (either building your own tag, or using `Html.BeginForm()` ) and then include inside that form's scope a submit button.

Comment: +1 on the GET. It's a partial view. The link bring user to the Edit form, which will have it's own form tag.

Comment: @IrishChieftain: Glad if it helps. I had the same problem in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Your BudgetsController should look like below **without HttpPost Attribute** and **without Route Attribute** as you are using method names in ActionLink. You can use HttpGet attribute if you wish.

Also no need of **FormCollection collection** parameter in EditBudget method. You will not get anything as its Get not Post.

```
public ActionResult EditBudget(int? id = null)
{
}

public ActionResult EditAccountBudget(string account)
{
}
```

Comment: Plus vote on the GET. I was eventually able to get it to work and will post my answer.